# Are U.S. Social Security payroll contributions and state taxes deductible from taxable income for India?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, india, social-security, dtaa

I moved to USA during the financial year Apr 2014 - Mar 2015, in which I was resident in India for more than 182 days due to which my status is "resident" in India for the tax year concerned. I understand, according to income tax law in India, my global income will be taxable in India, which means I will need to pay tax in India on my salary income in USA.

I know that federal income tax paid in USA will be considered towards tax paid and I get credit for that when computing tax amount for India. I have doubts for following two items:

1. Social Security Tax
2. U.S. State Income Tax

Are above two items exempt when computing taxable income in India for the year?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the [DTAA](http://www.incometaxindia.gov.in/Pages/international-taxation/dtaa.aspx) the Social Security Tax is not considered. There is no mention of State Tax. As per the definition, only Federal Tax is considered.

Comment: can we consider State Tax also then?

Comment: If taxes apart from Federal is not considered, shouldn't we reduce these amount from the total income while filing tax in India?

Comment: Yes. However it is best consult a professional CA.

Answer (score 3):

The Section 91 gives out the permissible deduction for countries where DTAA is not present. As per [section 91 of Indian income tax](http://www.incometaxindia.gov.in/pages/acts/income-tax-act.aspx) act you can claim the benefits of state tax even though the DTAA does not have any provision of this. This was the ruling in the case of [DCIT Vs Tata Sons as listed here](http://itatonline.org/archives/dcit-vs-tata-sons-itat-mumbai-foreign-income-taxes-not-eligible-for-deduction-us-371-despite-bar-in-dtaa-credit-for-state-taxes-to-be-given-us-91-in-addition-to-federal-taxes/).

There is no reference of such relief available for social security tax & medicare tax

Answer (score 2):

As per some of the [blogs](http://www.taxdost.com/state-income-taxes-in-the-usa-and-canada-are-eligible-for-foreign-tax-credit-under-section-91-of-the-income-tax-act-despite-dtaa-allows-only-federal-tax/) on this topic

> 6) While the title of section 91 of Indian Income Tax suggests that it
>   is applicable only in cases where India has not entered into a double
>   taxation avoidance agreement with the respective jurisdiction, but the
>   scheme of section 91, read along with section 90, does not reflect any
>   such limitation. Section 91 is, thus, required to be treated as
>   general in application.
>
> 7) The fact that a taxpayer is entitled to make a particular claim, in
>   accordance with a tax treaty provisions, does not disentitle him to
>   make the claim in accordance with the provisions of the Act if it is
>   more beneficial to him.
>
> **Conclusion**
>   "The Mumbai bench of Income-tax Appellate Tribunal (the Tribunal) in
>   this case held that US federal tax and state tax paid in respect of
>   income earned overseas are not deductible as expenditure incurred for
>   earning income under section 37 of the Income-tax Act, 1961 (the Act).
>   Further, the Tribunal observed that, though relief is not available
>   for state income taxes paid under the India- US tax treaty (tax
>   treaty), the relief is available under Section 91 read with Section 90
>   of the Act."

This means we should able to claim State tax, and few other places it is also written that we can claim "medial" and "social" taxes as well.